# SQL Server Management Studio And Network Server Discovery

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio, version 18.9.1, on a Windows 10 system. The installed Management Studio cannot discover known SQL Server databases out on the network, so I cannot log into a SQL Server using SQL authentication.

Please note, the target SQL Server has been installed for a while, and is running fine. I am trying to access this SQL Server from a new workstation.

The SQL Server Browser is running on the SQL Server I am trying to reach.

I am confused as to what should be installed if what I installed is not correct. I'm also confused as to which services to check are installed after installation. It doesn't look like a SQL Agent or locator service was installed, after I installed SQL Server Management Studio.

Am I better off installing a development database and just not using it in order to get the locator service?

[image]

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE, have you installed SQL Server or is there actually an instance on your network? If there is one, is the browser service on that host running? If not, and it's not running intentionally, have you tried putting in the server name (and instance name if required) for your Server Name yourself?

Comment: Are your Sql Browser services running?

Comment: How do I get them installed? I did not see anything like that.

Comment: *"How do I get them installed?"* By downloading the setup file and running it.

Comment: That image shows you *have* installed SQL Server and you've successfully connected. So what is the problem here?

Comment: @Stu Yes, the SQL Browser is running on the target SQL server.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I am trying to reach a real SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu I can't get a client to connect.

Comment: That isn't a "real" server? What do you mean by a "real" server?

Comment: Sounds like as it's a new workstation you probably have a firewall or routing issue. Can you telnet to the target server by IP on 1433? Can you ping the workstation from the server?

Comment: Also confused by *It doesn't look like a SQL Agent or locator service was installed, after I installed SQL Server Management Studio* - SSMS doesn't install these, they're part of the Sql Server installation.